# How to add color to listplot

Tags: plotting, color

I have generated many points in a 2-dimensional space (x,y). How do I use color to represent different values of f(x,y) in `ListPlot`? Does `ColorFunction` apply to this case? Also how to make a barlegend for this color distribution?

Comment: In the current form your question is rather ambiguous. What have you tries? You may want to add an example to your question together with a description how the output should look like. Did you see http://wolfram.com/xid/0wgs3aa-7abkax and http://wolfram.com/xid/0wgs3aa-qndjj3?

Comment: Or are you looking for [`ListDensityPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListDensityPlot.html) or [`ListContourPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListContourPlot.html)?

Comment: Check Menu/Help/WolframDocumentation/ListPlot/Options/ColorFunction and ColorFunctionScaling. There you will find a number of examples of how to do what you need.

Comment: I find this question to be off-topic, since it is fully answered in the documentation. I propose to close it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build it from graphics primitives.  Start by reading [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html), [`Point`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Point.html), [`ColorData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorData.html), [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html), [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html), [`Legended`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Legended.html), [`BarLegend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarLegend.html).

This is some example data

```
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {20, 3}];
```

The range of my data ($f(x,y)$ values) is $[-1,1]$.  We define it explicitly.

```
min = -1;
max = 1;
```

Make the plot:

```
g = Graphics[{
   PointSize[Large],
   {ColorData["ThermometerColors"][Rescale[#3, {min, max}]], 
      Point[{#1, #2}]} & @@@ pts
   }
  ]
```

Make the legend:

```
legend = BarLegend[{"ThermometerColors", {min, max}}]
```

Assemble them:

```
Legended[g, legend]
```

Comment: +1 for pedagogical patience and "in depth" make