# 2-dimensional scatter plot of a 3d dataset

Tags: plotting

I am fairly new to mathematica, I have been trying to find some inbuilt plotting function that lets us plot a scatter plot of a dataset: (x,y,f(x,y)), where color of the plot is based on value of f(x,y); something like matplotlib.pyplot.scatter; for example if I have a dataset: data= {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},...,{1001,1002,1003}}; and I would like to make a plot like in ListPlot and color the data based on #[[3]]&/@ data; Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may find [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104890/1063) helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

SeedRandom[1234];

data = {#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[1]]^2 + #[[2]]/2} & /@
   RandomReal[5, {100, 2}];

funcRange = MinMax[data[[All, 3]]];

Legended[
 Graphics[{
   AbsolutePointSize[4],
   {ColorData["Rainbow"][
       Rescale[#[[3]], funcRange]],
      Point[Most@#]} & /@ data},
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {x, y})],
 BarLegend[{"Rainbow", funcRange},
  LegendLabel -> Style["f", 14]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bob, this works great, I was exactly looking for this kind of solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
t = Partition[Range[1, 1003], 3];

ListPointPlot3D[t, ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][#3] &)]
```

[image]

---

**EDIT-1**

The closest visualization I can think of for 2D is a `ListContourPlot`, otherwise it will be a grid of points with different colors.

```
ListContourPlot[
 Table[Sin[x] Cos[y], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/50}, {y, 0, 
   2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/50}], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

---

**EDIT-2**

```
t4 = Array[(Sin[(2 \[Pi] #1)/100] Cos[(2 \[Pi] #2)/100]) &, {100, 
    100}] // N

ArrayPlot[t4, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> Automatic]
```

[image]

---

**EDIT-3**

Using `ListPlot` and creating a mock example conforming to a  Binormal distribution.

```
PDF[BinormalDistribution[{50, 50}, {20, 20}, 0], {x, y}]
```

$$\frac{\exp \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(-\frac{1}{400} (x-50)^2-\frac{1}{400} (y-50)^2\right)\right)}{800 \pi }$$

Define a function and generate `dataxy` randomly.

```
fz[{x_, y_}] := 
  PDF[BinormalDistribution[{50, 50}, {20, 20}, 0], {x, y}];

dataxy = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[{50, 50}, {20, 20}, 0], 
   1000];

dataz = Rescale[fz[#] & /@ dataxy];
```

Generate the list of 3-tuples:

```
alist = MapThread[Flatten[Join[{#1, #2}]] &, {dataxy, dataz}];
```

Before we color the points, let's see what these look like:

```
ListPlot3D[alist]
```

[image]

Give each point a color based on `#[[3]]`

```
ListPlot[Style[#[[{1, 2}]], Hue@#[[3]]] & /@ alist
 , PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.007], 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{Hue, {0, 1}}]]
```

[image]

I have benefitted from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1300/listplot-with-each-point-a-different-color-and-a-legend-bar/149214#149214) answer by @becko for the final part.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Syed; Is it possible get this done in 2D as well?

Comment: Thanks for suggesting ListContourPlot, however as you have mentioned is this possible to make 2d representation like a grid of points with different colors, if possible how can I plot that?

Comment: Thanks Syed, both the ListPlot and ArrayPlot solutions are really useful for my case, only problem is that I have a dataset with ~40000 points, so the ListPlot solution provided by you takes a long time to run

Comment: I would suggest that you start a fresh post and use the `performance-tuning` tag to address speed issue. There are many `Graphics` solutions on this page and if none of them have worked for your case then explain what you are looking for in a fresh post.